# Is there any way to create empty folder in Artifactory repo

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

I wanted to create empty folder in artifactory repo.
I created an empty folder with desired name in local file system and given that path to `jf rt u` command.

```
jf rt u <path/to/empty/folder> <destination/to/artifactory>
```

But it didn't work.
Is there any other way to create empty folders in artifactory repo.

Thanks in advance ...!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, **Artifactory doesn't** natively **support creating empty folders** directly.

One workaround is to create an empty file within the folder and then upload it. You could use a command like `touch` or similar to create an empty file within the folder and then upload that to Artifactory.

Here's a step-by-step process in doing so:

1. Create an Empty File:

On your local system, navigate to the desired folder and create an empty file using the command line. For example:

```
touch emptyfile.txt
```

This command creates an empty file named emptyfile.txt.

2. Upload the Empty File to Artifactory:

Use the jf rt u command to upload the empty file to Artifactory. Modify the command according to your specific paths:

```
jf rt u /path/to/emptyfile.txt <destination in Artifactory>
```

Replace `/path/to/emptyfile.txt` with the actual path to your empty file and  with the path where you want to upload the empty file.

3. Result:

Once the empty file is uploaded to Artifactory, it will appear as a file. However, since it's an empty file, it effectively creates the appearance of an empty folder within Artifactory.

This method essentially tricks Artifactory into displaying an empty folder by uploading an empty file within it.

Comment: its not working for me either. It doesn't show any error msg but status says "success" but "totals": "success" : 0

Comment: Its giving 409 error saying, "expected a file but found a folder". I am proving path to file: jf rt u ./EmptyFolder/emptyfile.txt <destination in Artifactory>".

Comment: It appears this post was in whole or in part created with AI tools. Please note that [Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831) and read [Help Center: AI policy](/help/ai-policy).
It is not permitted to use AI tools to generate or reword content that you post on Stack Overflow, even if you vet this content beforehand. Work of others without [attribution](/help/referencing) also constitutes plagiarism. __Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.__

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Alternative way to using JFrog CLI
is to create a folder using the Artifactory REST API, you should indicate your intention by adding a forward slash at the end of the folder name in the API endpoint. This helps Artifactory understand that you want to create a folder rather than a file.

Example:

```
curl -u<username>:<password> -XPUT "http://my.jfrog.artifactory:8081/artifactory/generic-local/a/"
```

This will upload a directory called 'a' under an existing repository generic-local of type 'Generic'

Note: The generic-local should exist prior to adding the sub folder.

Comment: its giving me 403 if i try with given curl command

Comment: Make sure the given credentials are correct, HTTP 403 is an HTTP status code meaning access to the requested resource is forbidden.

Possible issues: 
1. The given credentials are wrong.
2. The access to the specific repository key is forbidden due to permission target configuration.

Try using the same credentials for executing an artifact upload to the repository. https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/deploy-artifact